# iOS 7 CoreData - FetchedProperty returns faulting array

Tags: core-data, ios7, fetched-property

maybe someone could tell me if i am on the right way.

I have two entities:

**Exercise** with following attributes: 
*title - string* ; *exercise_id - int*

**AddedExercise** with following attributes:
*count - int* ; *added_exercise_id - int*

The **AddedExercise** has a fetched property called *link_exercise* with Destination: **Exercise**
and predicate: exercise_id == $FETCH_SOURCE.added_exercise_id

In my code i do the following:

```
for(AddedExercise *e in listOfAddedEx){
            [moc refreshObject:e mergeChanges:YES];
            NSLog(@"%@", e.link_exercise);
        }
```

And the log says:

**Relationship fault for (), name link_exercise, isOptional 1, isTransient 1, entity AddedExercise, renamingIdentifier link_exercise, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, fetchRequest  (entity: Exercise; predicate: (exercise_id == $FETCH_SOURCE.added_exercise_id); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ) on 0x1700d8b80**

So it seems like something is there, represented in a fault.
But if i try to access the "link_exercise" array. For example with:
*e.link_exercise.count* or *e.link_exercise.lastObject*

I'll get the following error:

**'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID 0xd000000000040002> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key added_exercise_id.'**

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve that.

Many thanks in advance.

S.R.

**-----> UPDATE 1:**

I changed now the predicate to:
*SELF.exercise_id=exercise_id*

Now i can access the **Exercise** object but i get a wrong id, because

*SELF.exercise_id=exercise_id* should look like *SELF.exercise_id=**added_exercise_id***

With predicate *SELF.exercise_id=**added_exercise_id*** i get the following error:

**'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (exercise_id == added_exercise_id) (problem on RHS)'**

**-----> UPDATE 2:**

Still cannot figure out why it isn't working...

For me it seems like

```
SELF.exercise_id == $FETCH_SOURCE.added_exercise_id
```

should be the right predicate, but it doesn't work.
Maybe someone else has some suggestions...?

Or should i create a fetch request by myself (programmatically) ? 
That means set up a fetch request to all "Exercise"s and give the one back where exercise_id = added_exercise_id. This is basically that, what i currently try to solve through a fetched property.

**-----> UPDATE 3:** 
Ok i nearly have it!! One thing i forgot to mention is, that i use a multi managedObjectContext core data stack (Including a worker-, main- master-context)

```
masterContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
masterContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
[masterContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];

mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
mainContext.parentContext = masterContext;

workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
workerContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
workerContext.parentContext = mainContext;
```

All my request go to the **worker-context** (in this case the fetched proper doesn't work)
BUT if all my requests go to the **master-context** the fetched property works as expected!!

So it seems like it only works with the managedObjectContext which has the persistent store.

**Can somebody explain me, why this cannot work with an other managedObjectContext?**

Comment: Perhaps try some `isKindOfClass` checks.

Comment: Ok... i am one step closer. With the following predicate:
"SELF.exercise_id=exercise_id" the exception doesn't occur. But the second "exercise_id" should be the "added_exercise_id"

Comment: Use $FETCH_SOURCE on the RHS (righthand side) ??

Comment: Then this here will be thrown: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID 0xd000000000040002> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key added_exercise_id.'

Comment: I also thought $FETCH_SOURCE is my "AddedExercise" object. But seems like it is not... :-/

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But there is still a problem on the RHS: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSFetchedPropertyDescription 0x1782e4b00> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key added_exercise_id.' But as the docs says: "The source refers to the specific managed object that has this property..." I understand, that $FETCH_SOURCE is in my case the  "AddedExercise" object. But then i have no idea why i can't access the added_exercise_id property...

Comment: I was mixing up your LHS and RHS, and I agree with you.  Deleting previous unconstructive comment.  Also, $FETCH_PROPERTY appears to just be a way to get to a userInfo dictionary inside the property description if one is defined.  If you've tried `SELF.exercise_id == $FETCH_SOURCE.added_exercise_id` and it didn't work, I got nothing.  Good luck.

Comment: Actually, one more comment.  The error message about SQL-- the Apple docs do mention that some things don't work with SQL.  You could try XML.

Comment: Verifying--the fix seems to be to access the fetched property from a managed object retrieved from the root managed object context. We have the same Core Data stack setup as I am using [BNRCoreDataStack](https://github.com/bignerdranch/CoreDataStack). I now create my managed objects on the main queue then save them (recursively to the root--`BNRCoreDataStack` takes care of this), and then re-fetch my fetched results controller whose MOC is the root.